# Reported speech of "conditional sentences"

Tags: grammar

what should be the reported speech of the following sentence?

> John said, "Paul would help us if we needed a volunteer."

Should I report it this way?

> John said that Paul **would help** us if we **needed** a volunteer.

(or)

> John said that Paul **would have helped** us if we **had needed** a volunteer.

[This site](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/reported-speech/reported-speech-indirect-speech) says "We can use a perfect form with have + -ed form after modal verbs, especially where the report looks back to a hypothetical event in the past."

The site also says modal verbs like would, should and might remain unchanged. Then which of my above answers is correct?

Comment: If you could still benefit from the help, if you still need a volunteer, don't cast it in the perfect. The perfect implies that the need is a thing of the past.

Answer (score 1):

It's actually kind of *reported speech of reported speech*, isn't it?  As you know, we usually backshift verbs when indirectly reporting speech, but you should only backshift once.

Your example is a little odd because it's not clear when Paul's help is needed.  Logic says it's in the future, and so John is saying that Paul offered to help -- but in that case it seems more idiomatic to use *need*. The backshift to *needed* is what makes it sound like a direct quote of an indirect quote.  Normal conversation isn't that complicated:

> John said Paul would help us if we **need** a volunteer.

Still, *needed* is fine, and would likely pass without notice.

> John said Paul would help us if we **needed** a volunteer.

Although your reference says otherwise, there is no reason to shift from the simple past to a perfect tense. The perfect tense is normally used to establish a relationship between two events in time.  Your example is just a simple statement.  Changing it to the perfect only makes it more confusing.

However, the perfect tense *does* work if the help was needed in the past, and John is only now telling me that Paul offered help *at the time*.

> John said that Paul **would have helped** us if we **had needed** the help.  Gee, thanks John, for not saying something sooner.

Answer (score 1):

Saying

> John said that Paul would help us ...

is fine. Also fine is a slight reduction of that:

> John said Paul would help us ...

If you feel the need to stringently disambiguate your meaning, you could say

> John said Paul would have helped us if we had needed a volunteer.

but this feels over-particular and may cloud the issue instead of clarifying it, since inevitably some users will struggle to connect the dots with your perfect tensification.